# Is it possible to run a testcase as a test setup in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

I'm using soapUI.  I have an xml file with 200+ testcases in it, so obviously I don't want to run all of these tests all the time.  I have one test case that does the auth and sets a token as a property, which is then used by all the other test cases.

I want to make sure that if I run 1 test case or if I run 25 test cases each time the auth test case is run first.

Is there a way I can call 1 test case as a setup step to the test suite?

Comment: Yes it is, but one needs to understand more about your tests before helping.

Answer (score 0):

So for my needs, the answer is test suite setup only runs when the test suite itself is run.  If you run one of the test cases within the test suite, the test suite set up will not run.

So for me, running a setup step within the test suite setup was not a good solution, as if a user ran a single test case, the test suite setup would not work.

What I did was create a new test case and call that from each test case as a **Run TestCase TestStep**.